# Fingerprint reader doesn't work when computer is sleeping

Tags: windows, windows-10, biometrics

When my computer went to sleep I used to be able to put my finger on the fingerprint reader and the computer would wake up. After an update, it seems as if that went away, now I have to press a key or move the mouse to bring up the lock-screen, and then I can use the fingerprint reader.

Is there a way for me to fix this so that the fingerprint reader still works when the computer is asleep?

Comment: What kind of computer?  I have a ThinkPad X1 with Fingerprint Reader. I do not ever recall that the reader would un-suspend the computer. I tested it just now and the light over the reader remained off while suspended and turned on (green bar) when I pressed Fn to un-suspend and then the reader read my finger. So from my perspective, what you get (what I get) is normal.  Windows 10 V2004 19041.388 and all drivers /BIOS fully up to date.

Comment: @John I have a Lenovo YOGA C740. Maybe it was a BIOS update that disabled it or even removed it...

Comment: I cannot say for sure, but very up to date machines that I know of (not your particular model) keep the fingerprint reader off while suspended.